# How to calculate a UIView position relative to a background image on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have background image and want to be able to add `UIViews` to a certain point on that image. When it then loads on another device however it will be in a different place as the image frame is `self.view.bounds`.

Is there a way I can store the `UIViews` location relative to the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use below methods available in UIView.

- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(nullable UIView *)view;
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(nullable UIView *)view;
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(nullable UIView *)view;
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(nullable UIView *)view;